# How to download a file from github in a local directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, github

I am looking for a way to download a specific file from github using a PowerShell commands.

The URL to the file that I try to download is the following: https://github.com/soulcurrymedia/twitter-emotion-recognition/blob/master/models/allowed-chars.pkl

I have tried the following but it has downloaded html script rather than the actual file

```
$url = "https://github.com/soulcurrymedia/twitter-emotion-recognition/blob/master/models/allowed-chars.pkl"

$output = "C:\code\queues\models\allowed-chars.pkl"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
```

I am new to PowerShell so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a direct-download link for it to work.
In this case the link is:

```
https://github.com/soulcurrymedia/twitter-emotion-recognition/raw/master/models/allowed-chars.pkl
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this link for download the file:

https://github.com/soulcurrymedia/twitter-emotion-recognition/raw/master/models/allowed-chars.pkl